# SQL table - Data management

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a website where users can easily calculate the calories they eat and see the repartition in term of fat, carbo, etc.

I want the users to be able to retrieve data from previous days.

I then need to store the data sent by my users everyday (basically, they input how much of each food they have eaten everyday and I am making the calculation then store the results).

The question if the following: what would be the best way to store the data? I have to store the data for each user for each day. I can't think of a simple solution (I think creating a new table for each new day would not be great, would it?).

I'm using PHP and MySQL for now.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are a step ahead of your self with the daily breakdown question.

First, you need to decide what you need to store, e.g. fields and normalise the way they are stored.

For example, you would have the following tables:

**Users**:

- Id
- ..

**EatItems**:

- UserId
- ProductId
- Calories
- Fat
- DateTime

Once you have these tables up and running, you can build reporting layer on top of that to breakdown consumption by user / date or anything else you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a table that holds the input/calculated data/date which relates to a user/account.

When the user views previous day's, select the data that relates to that user.

I wouldn't create a table for each day. One table would suffice.

However, I would suggest attempting something and posting the code for specific issues you have if you run into before posting here.